# How to get parameter from a jsp that is included in a jsp that is included in the requesting jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, inheritance, jstl

I'm trying to set up a general use environment drop down selection (for queries) that is in its own JSP that is included in a header jsp that is included in a jsp that submits a request to a servlet.  However, I cannot access the environment drop down's parameter from the jsp (it returns null).  The JSP is written as follows:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:set var="base" value ="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale-1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${base}/path/to/css/maintEnvironmentCss.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-10">
            <div class="form-group">
                <form>
                    <select class="env-group" id="idname" name="idname">
                        //Properly formatted options (removed on SO for security reasons)
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

It is included in the header using JSTL

```
<jsp:include page="/path/to/jsps/maintEnvironment.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

Which is also included on the requesting jsp as such:

```
<jsp:include page="/path/to/jsps/header2.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

and I try to call it as such:

```
UnStickReports usr = new UnStickReports(request.getParameter("idname"));
```

But whenever I debug, the returned parameter is null which makes the servlet throw a nullpointerexception.  I know this is an inheritance issue, but, short of manually putting the menu manually on every page, what can I do to make the parameter inheritable?  I did try setting the selection as a session variable, but that also failed.

```
<script>
    function setEnv() {
        var env = document.getElementById("idname");
        session.setAttribute("attName",env.value);
    }
</script>
```

Using this, I still get null for the value using this:

```
UnStickReports usr = new UnStickReports((String) request.getAttribute("attName"));
```

I have seen the following suggestion from other similar questions:

```
<jsp:include page="callee.jsp" />
   <jsp:param name="param2" value="value2" />
   <jsp:param name="param3" value="value3" />
</jsp:include>
```

But this overrides the values that should be passed from that jsp, which seems purposeless to me unless you need hardcoded values that require no user input.

Comment: if there are multiple forms in your final jsp,then depending on which form you r submitting,data will be available on server.See page source to understand more.The form data which you are submitting will be sent to server through request.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're saying.  Are you saying there is a function under the request object I have in the Servlet that will have access or that there is one on the jsp that will?  If it is the latter, how would I access/forward the information to the servlet?

Comment: in simple words,first you need to make sure that what is the data that is being sent to server in Request object.Check request.getParameterMap() at server.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do, is give the form a method, an action and then make sure the control is coming through, I am sure you will find something .

also what is this JSP code or JavaScript? looks like neither to me.

```
<script>
    function setEnv() {
        var env = document.getElementById("idname");
        session.setAttribute("attName",env.value);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That section is JavaScript.  I was looking for a way to set a session var from the jsp and that was what I found in my searching.  Yeah, I kinda realized a bit late it isn't involved in any form submission, now I'm scratching my head looking for a way to indirectly include it in the main submission.  Thank you!